# asp.net Model default value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model which is responsible for storing user's form inputs and do something with them. My question is how I can assign a default value to an optional field if it is null.

For example:
Model:

```
MyModel
{
    public int? Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditPrice(MyModel model)
{
    //Do something
}
```

View:

```
@model MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price )
}
```

if the user leaves the text box as empty then model.Price would be null, I want to know how I can assign a default value like -1 if Price is null.

Note setting it in constructor would not work since it will get overwrite once the user Posts the new value `Price = null` to the controller.

`Price = -1` is a convention I use for something, and Null means something else so I can't leave it as null in the data base. I know I can do a check like `model.Price = model.Price??-1;` But I am looking for a cleaner way of doing this.

Edit: 
With the parameter way i can do something like

```
public ActionResult EditPrice(int? price = -1)
{
    //Do something
}
```

I am basically looking for a way to achieve the same result with Model

Comment: If "null means something" how are you going to distinguish between a "meaningful" null and a "use the default" null?

Comment: How do you retrieve the value for the database? Is adding a getter implementation that returns -1 on a null value not an option?

Comment: @DStanley null can only be inserted by the backend logic, not from the user, the user's null should be convert to -1

Comment: @Dan well it is an option but I always prefer a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any class you can assign defaults in the constructor.

```
MyModel
{
   public int? Price { get; set; }

   public MyModel() {
     Price =  -1;
   }
}
```

Comment: well i said constructor won't work since the value will get overwrite once the form posts the data to controller